# Loops rendered by graphviz are messy

Tags: graphviz

I am trying to generate an automata with a single state and 4 self-edges. The basic dot code looks like this:

```
digraph G {
splines=true;
overlap=scalexy;
rankdir="BT";
T[label="0" shape=doublecircle]
T -> T [label="a:a"];
T -> T [label="b:b"]; 
T -> T [label="a:"];
T -> T [label="a:"];
}
```

The output is quite messy and trying out parameters like `minlen` hasn't helped (it doesn't seem to change anything). I also want the edges to be displayed on the top/in the vertical direction, but graphviz displays them on one side. How do I fix this?

Current output:

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `rankdir="RL"` and connect from east to west (`T:e -> T:w`) you get pretty close to what you are looking for:

```
digraph G {
  splines=true;
  overlap=scalexy;
  rankdir="RL";
  T[label="0" shape=doublecircle]
  T:e -> T:w [label="a:a"];
  T:e -> T:w [label="b:b"]; 
  T:e -> T:w [label="a:&epsilon;"];
  T:e -> T:w [label="b:&epsilon;"];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!